# Show link only to specific group

Tags: groups, configuration, audience-targeting, security-trimming

I have a page in which several sharepoint groups have access to. Picture a department page in sharepoint. On this page we have several webparts that we would like everyone to see. My question is, how can I show a link (or list of links) to only one specific group that has access to this page?

This seems so simple but I cannot figure out how to do it. I would like to avoid doing any development as well as multiple instances of this page (if possible). Maybe I am just having a slow monday morning....

Answer (score 4):

Create the links using a "Content Editor Web Part" and assign "Target Audiences" to that web part. So that the links can be targeted to appear only to people who are members of a particular SharePoint group or audience.

Reference Links:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906649(v=office.14).aspx
2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/1358f3a0-5b55-4df8-8fe9-7d59aec932d9

Answer (score 3):

You can either place your links as hyperlinks in a Content Editor web part or you can use the Summary Links web part and place that web part on your page.

Then "Edit Web part" >> Advanced >> Target Audience >> Add or Select your Group. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*As an alternative to Groups based restriction, you could use Permission based:*

You can use security trimming within SharePoint Designer to do this.  Put html code within the following brackets:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="">
```

Within the Permissions parameter change the role level to the appropriate setting.  Here is site where you can get all permissions available: http://sharepointgauravgoyal.blogspot.com/search/label/SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Comment: This would be alternative method if audiences is not available (e.g. SharePoint Foundation).

Comment: This does not appear to target a sharepoint group but more a permission level... am I wrong?

Comment: That is correct.  SPSecurityTrimmedControl does not target a specific SharePoint group but rather permission sets.  If all groups have same permissions on site, you could hide through SPServices.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetGroupCollectionFromUser&referringTitle=Users%20and%20Groups

First, hide all webparts before SPServices is called within documentready function.  Then create some if/else if statements within completefunc and use .show() method to show the webparts appropriately based on group membership.  This is not a security measure!  This is just UI changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use audiences.  Define the audience you want to be able to view the links, and then use a webpart targeted to that audience. Audiences have to be defined in Central Administration, they are specified in the web parts under their "advanced" menu.