# Creating Quick Links Web Part

Tags: 2013, web-part, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2013.

There are four lists:
List1
List2
List3
List4

With different users assigned to each List.
Now, In the Home Page, I want to insert a Web Part named "Quick Links".

Whenever a user from List1 logs in, only List1 link should be displayed.
All the other three links should be invisible for the List1 user.

Same applies to the other three List users too.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Similar case: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70724/show-link-only-to-specific-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to set up the lists with the different permissions to lock down what the users have access to. You could then use a content search webpart to return only lists. This should run the query using the authenticated user so they will only be able to see the lists that they have permissions for.